# how can i get contents of word page in Office 365 app

Tags: office365, word-addins

I am creating an Office 365 word application, in which I want to get all the contents (text + images) of page. Currently I am using **getSelectedDataAsync()** function but in this case I need to select all the contents.

Is there any other way to get all contents without selecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you were using the Office 2016,Word for iPad, Word for Mac, we can use the code below to get the text of Word document:

```
 function getDataFromBody() {
    // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
    Word.run(function (context) {

        // Create a proxy object for the document body.
        var body = context.document.body;

        body.load("text");

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
        // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync().then(function () {              
            console.log("Body txt contents: " + body.text);
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

You can refer to the new version of API from [here](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body).

## Update

Get the Html of body content for Word:

```
   function getDataFromBody() {
    // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
    Word.run(function (context) {

        // Create a proxy object for the document body.
        var body = context.document.body;

        // Queue a commmand to get the HTML contents of the body.
        var bodyHTML = body.getHtml();

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
        // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            console.log("Body HTML contents: " + bodyHTML.value);
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually I am creating this app for word online of Office 365. Also I need the contents in HTML format.

Comment: To get the HTML content, instead of using the **text** property, we can use the **getHtml()** methoed. See the update.